# Unit testing mirkoORM entities

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mikro-orm

I'm trying to unit test a method in a MikroORM entity and thus to populate a mikroORM `collection` field with test data. (I use jest) :

```js
describe('Team Tests', () => {
    it('isLeader should return true when given user is the team leader', () => {
       // Given
        const team = new Team('Test team');
        const user = new User('Test User', 'test@test.fr');

        team.members.add(new TeamMember(user, TeamRole.Leader));

        // When
        const result = team.isLeader(user.userId);

        // Then
        expect(result).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

However, when I run my test, I hit the following error when adding the data to the collection :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
    at Collection.get property [as property] (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\entity\ArrayCollection.js:123:44)
    at Collection.validateItemType (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\entity\Collection.js:317:71)
    at C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\entity\Collection.js:111:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Collection.add (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\entity\Collection.js:111:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\src\teams\team.entity.spec.ts:11:22)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:390:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:315:10)
    at _callCircusTest (C:\Users\arsen\git\HorizonWeb\api\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:218:40)
```

Any idea of how to properly unit test a MikroORM entity ?

Comment: Had same issue as you @Ombrelin; would love if MikroORM made more out of their testing docs. Because it is a really great library, but it's difficult for idiots like me to get started with proper unit testing

Comment: Haha completly agree ! For the record, what I did is completly abstract my logic layer since I used TDD, and use distinct class for business entity and persistence entity. I wish ORM frameworks would have feature helping us in that way

Comment: v5 has some cool additions, like a Database seeder that at least makes some of the testing easier. How do you properly unit test when your service makes use of complex queries, e.g. with model relationships and what not?

Comment: Hey, guys! Can anyone please post an example (maybe @Ombrelin as part of the issue description, maybe someone else as an answer that we can actually upvote) for this case? I would love to see an example to make it work in my current project. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the ORM first to work with the entities. For unit tests where you do not want to touch the database, you can use the second parameter to not connect to the database, but the entity discovery needs to happen. Without that there is no metadata and no patched entity prototypes - and that is needed for propagation to work.